# What is the meaning of & in c++?

Tags: c++, syntax, reference

I want to know the meaning of & in the example below:

```
class1 &class1::instance(){

///something to do

}
```

Comment: To everything else @Wim said, I'll add that it's clearer if you write it as `class1& class1::instance()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the ampersand for when used after class name like ostream& operator <<(...)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1572016/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means your method returns a *reference* to a method1 object. A reference is just like a pointer in that it refers to the object rather than being a copy of it, but the difference with a pointer is that references:

- can never be undefined / NULL
- you can't do pointer arithmetic with them

So they are a sort of light, safer version of pointers.

Comment: Example of usage would be nice

Comment: @daemonfire300: There was a usage example in the question.

Answer (score 8):

The `&` operator has three meanings in C++.

- "Bitwise AND", e.g. `2 & 1 == 3`
- "Address-of", e.g.: `int x = 3; int* ptr = &x;`
- Reference type modifier, e.g. `int x = 3; int& ref = x;`

Here you have a reference type modifier. Your function `class1 &class1::instance()` is a member function of type `class1` called `instance`, that returns a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29)-to-`class1`. You can see this [more clearly](http://kera.name/articles/2010/05/tomalaks-monday-monstrous-rant-i-align-your-asterisks/) if you write `class1& class1::instance()` (which is equivalent to your compiler).

Comment: I think `&` and `*` binding to the right in declarations is so important that it drowns out all the arguments for putting them with the type, as laid out in that article you linked.  This is probably because I grew up on old-fashioned C where "`int a, b, *c;`" is good idiom.

Comment: Technically speaking they bind to the right in the grammar, yes. I did mention this in the article, and I fail to see how that "drowns out" the other arguments. The entire point of the article is that, no, that is _not_ the most important consideration at all. The idea about computers is to aid humans: let's write code that makes sense to _us_, not code that matches the language of the computers at our expense.

Comment: But in this case, if you format the code in the way that "makes sense" to a human (treating the modifier as part of the type specifiers rather than as part of the declarator, in standard-ese) you put yourself at risk of bugs because *the computer doesn't treat them that way*.  To adapt the computer to the human in this case would require a change to the *language definition*, which we cannot do without a time machine; failing that, the best available option is the one which makes it evident to human readers how the compiler will interpret the code.

Comment: @Zack: Which, in this case, means indicating that the function will return a reference by demonstrating -- as tightly as possible -- a return type of `class1&`. The only bugs likely to show up with this habit are in multi-declaration of pointers, which I dismiss in my article as an over-rated fringe case not outweighing other considerations, such as those which led to this question's creation.

Comment: I can't agree with you.  In my opinion, the position of the `&` (same same `*`) makes *no difference* in the clarity of the return type in the original example, but the multi-declaration scenario is real and not remotely a fringe case. I've seen people make that mistake even in supposedly modern, one-decl-per-line C++. There is also an argument that cuddling modifiers to the left when they don't bind that way can teach people to misinterpret more complex declarators, such as when pointers-to-functions come into play (but I'd admit that my personal rule there is always use a typedef).

Comment: @Zack: Perhaps you don't deal with language newcomers as often as I do then. It's a stumbling block for almost _everyone_ that I've seen come to the language, when they can't visualise the different meanings of `*` and `&`. There is, of course, argument either way.

Comment: People are only newcomers to the language for a short while, but they might have to work with this or that giant grotty codebase for their entire career (that's certainly a good summary of mine).  I can see how the `*`-left style might soften the initial learning curve.  However, it does so by giving people the mistaken impression that the modifier binds leftward, which must at some point be unlearned, and so *lengthens* the time to come to full proficiency.

Comment: @Zack: There's certainly a case there. Personally I feel that by the time the programmer is in a situation where this behaviour needs to be "unlearnt", they're experienced such that it's not so much unlearning as adding to their knowledge. So I put the emphasis on the initial learning curve. And at that point, I guess it _really_ is down to personal opinion.

Comment: I'm not really sure that learning how the modifier binds _in the grammar_ is any sort of prerequisite to full proficiency, when the modifier binds to the left semantically. Surely that's all you need to know in order to use it. To become a guru it may be passingly interesting to know how your tokens are interpreted syntactically, but it has zero effect whatsoever on your ability to program. Ever.

Answer (score 1):

Its a reference (not using pointer arithmetic to achieve it) to an object.

Comment: What about in the given context?

Answer (score 1):

It returns a reference to an object of the type on which it was defined.

Comment: Example of usage would be nice

Comment: @daemonfire300: There was a usage example in the question.

Comment: @daemonfire300: Example of usage is I am not Google, my answer provides more than enough to find examples on a dozen websites.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the statement it looks like it would be returning a reference to the class in which is was defined. I suspect in the "Do Stuff" section is a

```
return *this;
```

Comment: This is a very dangerous assumption.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the variable it is not the variable itself, but a reference to it. Therefore in case of its value change, you will see it straight away if you use a print statement to see it. Have a look on references and pointers to get a more detailed answer, but basecally it means a reference to the variable or object...