# Puzzling C++ syntax using "&"

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the meaning of & in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289572/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-c)

Here is a C++ class declaration snippet containing an ampersand that doesn't make sense to me:

```
class rimage : public matrix {  
public:  
    rimage( void );  
    rimage( int, int );  
    rimage( rimage & );  
    rimage & operator=( const matrix & A );  
    rimage & operator=( const rimage & A );  
    rimage & operator/=( int );  
...
```

What does `rimage( rimage & );` mean? Why is the `&` at the end?

This snippet was from a text book on PCNNs

This class declaration is giving me compilation problems so I need to figure this out.

Comment: Not sure it was fair to mark as duplicate to the referenced entry. Yes that covers the `&` as stated, but the issue with the presented code is that this then becomes a non-const copy constructor.

Answer (score 4):

The declaration

```
rimage ( rimage & )
```

Might be easier to parse if you give the argument a name:

```
rimage ( rimage & A )
```

From this, it's a bit clearer that this defines a copy constructor that takes in another `rimage` by non-`const` reference.

More generally, when you leave the names of parameters out of function declarations, they can sometimes be a bit harder to read.  For example, this function

```
void DoSomething (int (int))
```

Can be hard to read, but if you add in a parameter name like this:

```
void DoSomething (int function(int))
```

Now you can see a bit more clearly that it's a function that takes another function in as a parameter.

For something even harder, consider

```
void DoSomething (int (&)[5])
```

With a parameter it's a bit easier to see what this is:

```
void DoSomething (int (&array)[5])
```

This is a function that takes in a reference to an array of five integers.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's a reference to an 'rimage' object

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references

It's probably just confusing you because it's unnamed in this declaration.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I've seen similar, more complete syntax elsewhere in the source code. Ah, the pitfalls of using code written by others. 'Tis both a blessing and a curse.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` signifies that it is an argument being [passed by reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29). In this case, the `rimage(rimage&)` is the declaration for a [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor).